# PHP file: most recent 11 files in folder AND subfolders

Tags: php, file, directory

I have a directory with about 100 sub-directories (nested, some 3-4 deep). I need a small PHP script that will simply output a list of the 11 most recently added (or modified, as they are all pdf's) files, with a simple `<br />` between each, each being linked to their URL.

I have found a few scripts that can do 1, or all, but have no clue how to even begin to limit to 11 specifically, or how to apply the exact href.

my alternate concern is server usage of this script, as it will be placed on a landing page that will see low usage, however every user will see it.

any ideas on resources to look into, or places to start, would be appreciated!

Comment: What OS is this running on?  Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, but it should work:

```
<?php

function getFiles($dir)
{
    $arr=scandir($dir);
    $res=array();
    foreach ($arr as $item)
    {
        if ($item=='..' || $item=='.'){continue;}
        $path=$dir.'/'.$item;
        if (is_dir($path))
        {
            $res=array_merge($res,getFiles($path));
        }
        else
        {
            $res[$path]=filemtime($path);
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

$files=getFiles('directory');
arsort($files);
$files=array_slice(array_keys($files),0,11);
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    echo '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: will this properly search subdirectories as well?

Comment: Yes, it will. The `getFiles` function is recursive.

Comment: I've got this put in place, however it is pulling 0 results (that I can see) - the 'directory' would just be /manuals in this case, correct, or do I need to do something specific for the recursion?

Comment: thanks so far Joel, I think that something server-side is limiting this, as the output to html is getting commented out IE:

<div id="list">
<!--?php function getFiles($dir) { $arr=scandir($dir); $res=array(); foreach ($arr as $item) { if ($item=='..' || $item=='.'){continue;} $path=$dir.'/'.$item; if (is_dir($path)) { $res=array_merge($res,getFiles($path)); } else { $res[$path]=filemtime($path); } } return $res; } $files=getFiles('../manuals'); arsort($files); $files=array_slice(array_keys($files),0,11); foreach ($files as $file) { echo '<a href="'.$file.'"-->
'.$file.'
<br>
'; } ?&gt;
</div>

Comment: Does your file have a ".php" extension, and is this code the only code in the file?

Comment: it has a .html extension, it is the only code (not counting css at top). 

only wierd caveat is that it is embedded in an Iframe that is then being referenced on another site that disallows php. I would assume that the PhP is processed first (as I have the rest of the page with an entire file listing script and everything after this landing page) and that would be unrelated

Comment: On most servers, a .html extension will not execute php. Try changing your file extension to .php . Being in an iframe should be fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12401/discussion-between-joel-and-user1298883)

Comment: just did, apparently scandir is not permitted, time to change the settings and it should work - thanks a ton man, really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to provide a web-based upload interface. That way you would be able to keep the track of each new upload.

- user chooses category (each category/subcategory maps to a folder)
- upload file(s) to server
- script dump each filename, location and date in table row

Done. To get latest 11 file (in entire system or specific category/folder)you need only query database.

If your users need the ability to remove files too, just add web interface for that functionality too. And instead of deleting the file, just mark them as "hidden" in the table.

Besides solving the immediate problem, it will also provide additional possibilities for moderation, attribution of ownership and search .. and many more.

Answer (score 0):

Use a RecursiveIterator. This is what it was designed for. I added an extra iterator named sortedIterator which extends SPLHeap, to sort by getMTime(), which is the modified time of the dir.

Change $path to be your full path to the directory.

```
$path = '.';

class sortedIterator extends SplHeap
{
    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator)
    {
        foreach ($iterator as $item) {
            $this->insert($item);
        }
    }
    public function compare($b,$a)
    {
        return strcmp($a->getMTime(), $b->getMTime());
    }
}

    $recursive = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
$sortByTime = new sortedIterator($recursive);
$i = 0;
foreach ($sortByTime as $file) {
        if($file->isDir()){
                $dirs[] = $file->getFilename();

                if($i++ == 9){
                        break;
                }
        }
}

print_r(implode("<br />", $dirs));
```

Edit, if you want Created Time, change getMTime to getCTime.

Answer (score -1):

Use the code that lists all of them, but before outputting use a [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) call to sort the files by decreasing modification time. Then, your loop should start with this:

```
$l = count($fileArray);
for( $i=0; $i<11 && $i<$l; $i++) {
    // output file entry
}
```

Comment: Why such inefficiency? He could have 100,000 files there, so he'll loop 100000 iterations to get 11 files?

Comment: it will be upwards of about 45,000 files to start, with roughly 100 added per week until potentially the end of time.

Comment: @Truth: Erm, no? The `$i<11` is there to stop the loop after 11 files. That being said, you do have to iterate to find the newest files.

Comment: it's the `usort()` that would be inefficient, not your `for` loop.

Comment: That's true. Ideally you should keep an array, keep track of the easliest time in it, then for each file check if its time is later - if it is, kick off the earliest time and add the new file, otherwise ignore the new file.